# SOAP Retrieve Automation in a Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

I would like to retrieve the ProgramID/ObjectID of an automation in a Business Unit, but the "ClientIDs.ID" or "Client.ID" doesn't seem to work.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>###</Username>
                <Password>###</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"> 
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
                <ID>123456</ID>
            </ClientIDs>
        <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType> 
        <Properties>ProgramID</Properties> 
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Properties>IsActive</Properties>
        <Properties>AutomationType</Properties>
        <Properties>ScheduledTime</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart"> 
                <Property>Name</Property> 
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator> 
                <Value>MyAutomation</Value> 
            </Filter>
        <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
        </RetrieveRequest>  
    </RetrieveRequestMsg> 
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the response: "No Rows were found".

Would anyone be able to help spot my mistake?

Comment: [Automation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/automation/) object doesn’t have `ProgramID` properties. Could you recheck your code

Comment: Hi Palash, this is a bug in the API, because calling the ProgramID is the only way to retrieve the ObjectID value, which is used to perform the automation.  Trying to retrieve the ObjectID results in an error: <Value>Invalid column name 'ObjectID'.</Value>.  More info can be found here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73634/automation-studio-error-automation-cannot-be-performed-automation-has-been-mar

Comment: Were you able to make this API work ? I am facing exactly same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are trying to retrieve the **ObjectID**, not ProgramID?

I've documented the steps to retrieve the ObjectID (and start an Automation) [on this page](https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md#retrieve-automation-objectid).

Comment: Hi Eliot, yes trying to retrieve the ObjectID via the ProgramID as per your page (thanks btw!).  I'm having trouble retrieving from a specific Business Unit, you wouldn't by any chance know how?

Comment: Try adding `<ClientIDs><ID>InsertMID</ID></ClientIDs>` within the `<RetrieveRequest>` element (for example, directly after that opening element), where `InsertMID` is the 7 digit MID associated with the Business Unit.

Comment: Hi @EliotHarper, I am facing exact same issue. When trying to retrieve ObjectId of Automation from Child BU, it throws 'No rows were found'. <ClientID> tag also doesn't help. Do you have any other suggestion

Comment: Are you using username/password Auth or OAuth credentials?

Answer (score 0):

The below call gets you the ObjectID of an Automation Program from a child BU. Just replace your BU MID and Program Name in the call below (along with username and password)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>xxxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yyyy</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
         <ClientIDs>
         <ID>12345</ID>
      </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>Program</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>Name</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>ABCDE</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```