# SFMC - Get all existing automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I want to create a landing page to list of all my existing automations in my SFMC account. Get the automation name, status, created date, activated data and last modified and owner.

I checked if SFMC has a dataview for this but it seems they have for Journeys only.

How can I get all of my automation details?

Thanks.

Comment: SOAP Requests to query your automations. Watch more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssjs via WSProxy with the Soap API:   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm

Or direcly the SOAP API.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm

[SOAP Retrieve Automation in a Business Unit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92527/soap-retrieve-automation-in-a-business-unit)